# Ruby on Rails ActiveResource::ServerError two apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with tow apps in ruby.

My first app, backend, works great, but when I want two connect second app with the first it show me an error:

```
 ActiveResource::ServerError in PagesController#index

Failed.  Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error .
```

I execute te first app (backend) in port 3000 and second app (frontend) 3001. The backend contains the conection to database, and works good, but when I connect the first app.
It throws me this error in backend:

```
...
Page Load (43.2ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = 10 LIMIT 1
  Rendered api/pages/show.json.rabl (2939.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3082ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass:
  app/models/post.rb:45:in `uri'
  (eval):143:in `block (2 levels) in eval_source'
  (eval):128:in `block in eval_source'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/builder.rb:152:in `node'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/builder.rb:114:in `block in compile_settings'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/builder.rb:113:in `compile_settings'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/builder.rb:58:in `block in to_hash'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/builder.rb:262:in `cache_results'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/builder.rb:49:in `to_hash'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/engine.rb:86:in `to_hash'
  rabl (0.11.5) lib/rabl/engine.rb:101:in `to_dumpable'
...
```

And this error in frontend:

```
...
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-29 04:31:44 +0100
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3179ms

ActiveResource::ServerError (Failed.  Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error .):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:9:in `index'


  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (18.7ms)
```

I have this in my config.yml (frontend):

```
common:

development:
  api: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/'

production:
  api: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

This in my page.tb (frontend):

```
class Page < ActiveResource::Base

  self.site = Baku.api
  self.format = :json

  def self.search(q,locale)
    result = Page.get(:search, q: "#{q}", locale: locale)
    object = OpenStruct.new(result)
    object
  end

end
```

This in Post.rb (frontend):

```
class Post < ActiveResource::Base

  self.format = :json

end
```

I don't understand the problem,I think that the conection between app is correct but it always show the error:

```
 ActiveResource::ServerError in PagesController#index

Failed.  Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error .
```

In line 45 of pos.rb I have:

```
def uri
    "/noticias#{self.widget.page.url}/#{self.name.parameterize}/#{self.id}"
end
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

This lines from your backend server's log

```
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass:
app/models/post.rb:45:in `uri'
```

tell you that you try to call `uri` on an object that is `nil` in line `45` of your `app/models/post.rb` file.

Have a look at line 45 in that file. If you are not able to figure out what is going on, then you might want to update your question with the code of that file.

---

With the new information: It seems like you have a `post` in your database, that has a `widget`, but the `widget` does not have a `page`. To fix that problem find that `widget` and assign a post to it. To avoid that problem in the future you might want to add a validator to `widget` that ensures the presence of a post.

Comment: In line 45 I have:

    `def uri
        "/noticias#{self.widget.page.url}/#{self.name.parameterize}/#{self.id}"
     end`

Editing the question.

Comment: @JohnIDelete: I updated my answer. `self.widget.page` returns nil. You hava a widget without a page. Therefore you cannot call `url` on it.